# Mongoid / Moped update an embedded document - ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, moped

I'm having trouble updating an embedded document in a Ruby / Sinatra app. I'm trying to use the positional operator "$" in an update statement in order to select the correct document from the embedded array. But this is throwing an "ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)" error.

A simple update statement with a hard-coded array index works fine. So maybe Mongoid/Moped doesn't support the position operator?... Although from what I could see, it looks like it should.

Does anyone know what the best approach is? Is there some other way to determine sub-document index without iterating through them all using Ruby in my controller - which is plan B, but seems really flaky!...

Here is my basic set up: I have "Customers"...

```
class Customer
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :customer_name, type: String

    embeds_many :contacts

    attr_accessible :customer_name
end
```

... with embedded "Contacts"...

```
class Contact
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :first_name, type: String

    attr_accessible :first_name

    embedded_in :customer
end
```

And in my controller I get the ._ids of both customer (pk), and the specific embedded document to update (contact_pk):

```
Customer.update(
                 { 
                   "_id" => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(pk),"contacts._id" => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(contact_pk)
                 },
                 {
                   $set => {"contacts.$.first_name" => "Bob" }
                 }
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` class method is actually `Customer.with_default_scope.update` in disguise, that means that `update` is actually the `update` method from `Mongoid::Criteria` and [that looks like this](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.6/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb#L379):

```
# Update the first matching document atomically.
#
# @example Update the first matching document.
#   context.update({ "$set" => { name: "Smiths" }})
#
# @param [ Hash ] attributes The new attributes for the document.
#
# @return [ nil, false ] False if no attributes were provided.
#
# @since 3.0.0
def update(attributes = nil)
  update_documents(attributes)
end
```

Notice that it only takes a single `attributes` parameter? That explains the error message. Presumably you're expecting `update` to work the same way as it does in the MongoDB shell or the JavaScript interface.

First you need to find the document of interest and then call `update` on that:

```
Customer.where('_id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(pk), 'contacts._id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(contact_pk))
        .update($set => { 'contacts.$.first_name' => 'Bob' })
```

Comment: That worked! I'm really struggling with the differences between MongoDB shell and what works in Ruby using Mongoid/Moped. Do you know of any tutorial or higher-level documentation that demonstrates how to put together Mongoid::Criteria based queries? Although this was exactly the steer I needed - thanks!